# Grammar about “would rather”

Tags: grammar

I would rather you “came” another time.
I would rather you “come” another time.

Could you please tell me what tense I should use in that kind of sentences?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your question could be improved by providing a minimal research you have done to answer this question yourself. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: See https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-grammar/would-rather

Comment: What Peter said, although there are some references around (from random people) who say the present tense can also be used and has a slightly different meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd rather you came another time

I might say this when someone suggests a time to arrive.

> I'd rather you come another time

However, I might say this when someone is here, and I want to turn them away. Importantly:

> I'd rather you come back another time

is fine, but

> I'd rather you came back another time

sounds kind of strange.

Based on [the article Peter linked](https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-grammar/would-rather), "came" is the correct form. As Paribus mentioned though, the present tense does sounds fine (I am one such random person).